# How to dynamically populate list box from database?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to dynamically populate list box from database? 
Please Provide some examples in zend framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say if you have a table called `Test` and a corresponding model for it named `Test`,

```
class Test extends Zend_Db_Table {

   protected $_name = "Test";

   function getLisItems() {
        $select = $this->getAdapter()->select()->from($this->_name, array(
                    'key' => 'column1_key',
                    'value' => 'column2_value'
                  ));
        return $this->getAdapter()->fetchPairs($select);
     }
}
```

In your controller action or view, have the following code.

```
$t = new Test();
$list = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('list');
$list->setLabel('Select your item: ')
->addMultiOptions($t->getLisItems());
```

Now your list box will be populated with items from the database.